# Code analysis warning on collection

Tags: asp.net

I am currently using the following to store collection of objects in session. However, I get a code analysis warning that "Collection property should be read only"

```
public class BankDetails
{
    //private constructor
    public string BankKey { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountHolder { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfAccount { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string Balance { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string Flag{ get; set; }
    public string NewContactType { get; set; }
    public string OwnerPlatFormID { get; set; }


    public static List<BankDetails> ExistingBankDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["ExistingBankDetails"] as List<BankDetails> ?? new

                List<BankDetails>();

        }
        set 
        { 
            HttpContext.Current.Session["ExistingBankDetails"] = value; 
        }
    }

    public static List<BankDetails> NewBankDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["NewBankDetails"] as List<BankDetails> ?? new

                List<BankDetails>();
        }
        set 
        { 
            HttpContext.Current.Session["NewBankDetails"] = value; 
        }
    }

    public void SetNewBankDetails(List<BankDetails> details)
    {
        details = NewBankDetails;
    }

    public void GetExistingBankDetails(List<BankDetails> existingDetails)
    {
        existingDetails = ExistingBankDetails;
    }
}
```

}

Any hints on rewriting this to pass the code analysis warning?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more normal to allow the collection to be modified, rather than to replace the entire thing on a set?  (also seems odd your getter doesn't fill in the session value, instead allowing multiple calls before set to create multiple collections)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
public static List<BankDetails> ExistingBankDetails
```

To this instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<BankDetails> ExistingBankDetails
```

And all other declarations as well.